# loading sass in a create-react-app with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, create-react-app

I recently migrated a create-react-app to typescript. After migration my scss files are being ignored in the .tsx components. I'm importing the files like so:

```
import './styles/scss/style.scss';
```

this was working fine in js. I've already installed node-sass and even tried installing @types/node-sass. I'd like to do this without ejecting. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: How did you migrate that code to typescript?

Comment: I used create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts to create a new app and moved the tsconfig.json, tslint.json files over to the existing app. Then just changed the .js files to .tsx

Comment: And did you remember to double check that the babel/webpack config(s) know that you're using sass? (because `create-react-app` does not prescribe any particular CSS preprocessor. If you're using sass, you're on the hook for making sure that babel and/or webpack follow the procedure for converting and including CSS defined using sass)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Where can I find the config files?

Comment: https://medium.com/@oreofeolurin/configuring-scss-with-react-create-react-app-1f563f862724

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is there any way to make this work without ejecting?

Comment: I don't understand why you would think that is a thing to ask about. You have needs that create-react-app does _not_ address, so no: you need to tell it "I have needs that you don't address, give me access to the configuration files". The alternative (which I personally prefer) is to not pretend your css is part of "a component", and maintain an organized collection of scss files that you build independently of your JS bundle, because that's easy and allows you to tweak CSS without rebuilds and full redeploys.

Comment: well, the latest version of create-react-app is configured to work with scss out of the box, so I was hoping there would be a way to make it work with typescript too. Thanks for the help, I guess I'll just go ahead and eject it.

Comment: @Deadmeat, I'm with you, the docs say it should work: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

But I'm having issues getting it to work in my typescript CRA as well. However, my issue is that the SASS imports don't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: hey @ZekeHernandez my issue was that I didn't update my react-scripts version. Make sure yours is 2.1

Comment: shoot, my issue is I'm using the wmonk typescript fork, not the official create-react-app. That's embarrassing.

Answer (score 1):

According with this documentation https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet#docsNav

If you use react-scripts@2.0.0 or higher just

```
npm install node-sass
```

restart and enjoy.